# Is my 7-year-old child sleeping too much?

Tags: sleep, primary-schooler, health

My child gets very tired and sleeps very easily. While parents of babies might find this a nice problem to have, in a 7-year-old it's possibly a concern. She easily sleeps up to 14 hours a night, also will still sometimes have a daytime nap like a preschooler. At bedtime she goes off very fast (like in 10 to 120 seconds) even if there's a lot of noise or excitement.

I don't want to exaggerate the "problem", she has never fallen asleep at school or while talking, or while sat at a table. She is very active and lively during the day. But she does seem to need an awful lot of sleep.

Recently she can't get up in the mornings in time for school, almost like a teenager, and is finding it hard to give her schoolwork any attention in the evening. Sure, getting up in the morning and doing homework, not easy for most children. But being such a big sleeper is starting to get in the way of these basics.

How much sleep is too much at that age?

Comment: Suggested edit to make the age more clear - I read twice and almost commented that the age would be helpful in answering the question. Maybe my eyes weren't working too well, but I think it would be clearer in the subject line.

Comment: This is a medical question (which of course parents need to be aware of) but might not be for this forum. My son, same age, slept alot and had trouble getting up in the morning. He was tested for sleep apnea and is about to get his tonsils out. Your situation might be different. Not sure if this should be a comment or an answer to your question.

Comment: My son is 6 1/2 and we are in the process of seeing infectious disease and neurologist. He goes thru spells of weeks at a time that he can't stay awake! Then he has a good week when all is normal. However, there are times I can't get him to wake up. He falls asleep as soon as he gets in the car from school and sleeps 3-4 hours gets up then goes to bed around 8:30. His has been going on for 2 months and is scary and very frustrating. he is missing school every 3rd day or so and sleeps all day. He has headaches that is the only other symptom. Does your daughter have any have other symptoms?

Comment: Iron deficiency is a possible cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Web MD](http://www.webmd.com/parenting/guide/sleep-children) a seven-year-old should get about 10 to 11 hours of sleep per day.

> **3-6 Years Old: 10 - 12 hours per day**
>
> Children at this age typically go to bed between 7 and 9 p.m. and wake up around 6 and 8 a.m., just as they did when they were younger. At 3, most children are still napping while at 5, most are not. Naps gradually become shorter as well. New sleep problems do not usually develop after 3 years of age.
>
> **7-12 Years Old: 10 - 11 hours per day**
>
> At these ages, with social, school, and family activities, bedtimes gradually become later and later, with most 12-years-olds going to bed at about 9 p.m. There is still a wide range of bedtimes, from 7:30 to 10 p.m., as well as total sleep times, from 9 to 12 hours, although the average is only about 9 hours.

That sounds like your daughter needs a little too much sleep, especially if it is starting to interfere with school. If it were me I would probably mention it to your doctor during the next check up.

Comment: Good to have some reference. I'd also ask the pediatrician about this; it might be nothing but it might be something! This is a question that we can't answer authoritatively on this site.

Comment: I might even bring it up and make an appointment about this problem rather than just waiting until the next check-up.  If there is something going on medically, getting a handle on it sooner rather than later is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my 7 year old son. Although he yawns through tiredness during the day, he is still very active. He goes to sleep quickly at 6:30/7:00 and wakes up tired at 6 a.m.

I took him to an [Ear Nose Throat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otolaryngology) Consultant and he had his tonsils and adenoids out in March.

They thought it may solve the problem, but thus far it hasn't.

Ask to see an ENT to see if her adenoids are blocking her airways and stopping her getting good quality sleep.

Good luck.